# Two form tags in asp.net page causes issues

Tags: asp.net, forms, tags

I have a search box which performs a search on any given keyword. It was working fine until another programmer added two form tags to the page which causes the url to load additional details while passing query string. When I comment any one of the tag, the query string is passed correctly. Can you please help with your valuable input?

Comment: Where is the Code you have been tried sofar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be one Form tag in the page. Please check below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc163736%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: One _server side_ form. And I don't think that's the issue, from the description.